# Webpack alias not resolving

Tags: webpack, alias

I've restructured some folders in my project and upon doing so, an alias I have setup doesn't work, this is the alias:

```
msp: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/mspComponents'),
```

My folder structure is:

```
config/
  index.js // this contains the webpack alias
src/
  components/
    mspComponents/
      generic/
        mspModal.vue
      index.js
```

index.js contains

```
import MspModal from './generic/MspModal.vue'
module.exports = {
  MspModal
}
```

When using `import { MspModal } from 'msp'` I get the error:

> 47:14-22 "export 'MspModal' was not found in 'msp'

This was working when I had the alias setup with a similar folder structure but coming out of the current project into an `msp-base/components/` folder.

What am I doing wrong? I'm a little baffled that it was working and isn't any more.

p.s If I need to provide more information about the structure or webpack config let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is weird because it was working before I moved folders around but I had to change my export declaration in `mspComponents\index.js` to

```
export { default as MspModal } from './generic/MspModal.vue'
```

This has resolved the issue but TBH, I don't know why.

Comment: Because the new version doesn't use the alias. (Aliases sometimes don't work, I'm on here looking for an answer to that)

Comment: The new version does use the alias, I still import it via: `import { MspModal } from 'msp'`. It was the export I had to change. As long as the alias is mapped correctly, I've never had an issue with them.

Comment: I should say: "Webpack 3 sometimes has problems with aliases, even if they resolve properly." Because that is the exact behavior I'm seeing. FWIW, I think it might have something to do with nested package.json's.